# How to calculate the time complexity for nested for loops in the following example?

Tags: python-3.x, time, time-complexity, complexity-theory

So in the following code, I am trying I am passing a (huge)number-string to the function where I have to find the maximum product of consecutive m digits

So, first, I am looping through let's say n-string and then the inner loop looping through m numbers. 
So the inner loop is affected by the `if-statement` which makes a jump of m indexes if the next number is 0.

**EDIT : 1**

Actual Problem Question:

The four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product are 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.

```
         731671765313306249192251....(1000digits)
```

Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product. What is the value of this product?

---

Example:
m = 12 number = "1234567891120123456704832...(1000 digits)"

- So in 1st iteration function will calculate the product of 1st 12 digits(i.e. from index-11 to index-0 - "**123456789112**0123456704832..."
- Now, in 2nd iteration when it checks the value at index-12 which is **0** then index will jump to **index-13**. This way the loop will skip 11 iterations.
- For the 3rd Iteration, the inner loop will execute for 4 iterations until it finds 0 ("01234567**0**4832...".

```py
def LargestProductInSeries_1(number,m):

    max = -1
    product = 1
    index = 0
    x = 0
    while index < len(number)-(m-1):
        for j in range(index+(m-1), index-1, -1):      
            num = int(number[j])
            if(not num):                            
                index = j
                break
            product = product * int(number[j])
        max = product if max < product else max
        product = 1
        index += 1
    return max
```

So according to me, the Worst Case Time Complexity would be `O(n*m)`

I think the Best Time would be `O(n/m)` if only once the inner loop is completely iterated or every mth digit is 0 which will make the outer loop execute but the index will jump to every mth digit.

Is my analysis correct?

What will be the Average Time for this case?

Will it be `O(n*(log m))`. Can anyone explain how? Or how to find  Complexity in such cases?

Comment: you seem to be mixing terminology and notation. Big O notation `O(...)` represents the upper bound based on the input. If you have a string of `n` numbers, then big O notation _only_  contains terms of `n`. There is no `O(n*m)`, because either `m` is an expression of `n`, in which case, expand that, or `m` is a constant and contributes nothing in the limit. As such, in terms of the actual expressions, `O(n*m)` and `O(n/m)` are _the same thing_: linear complexity, weighted by some constant.

Comment: Hi Mike, Thanks for your reply. consider an example that you want to traverse an `(n X n)` matrix in that case then the time complexity would be `O(n^2)` but let's say a matrix is `(m X n)`, in that case, it would be `O(m*n)`. Is it correct? isn't my question above similar to this?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans In my case m is not a constant. if m was constant I agree that `O(n*m) and O(n/m)` would have been linear.

Comment: Note that Big O notation is about the upper bound on complexity, as your input tends to infinity. For an `n x n` matrix we have a _set of elements_ that's size `n^2` elements, but a traversal complexity will be _linear_ on that set: the Big O notation is "O(n) where n is the number of elements we start with". In this case, we have some term confusion, as the `n` in "O(n)" and the `n` in "`n x n` matrix" are _different_ things.

Comment: Whether the matrix is `n x m` or `n x n`, the iteration complexity is the same: after counting the number of elements using `n = rows * columns`, we get O(n) regardless of the matrix dimensions. So when your post talks about `n/m` and `n*m`, those are not actually the quantities that Big O notation is concerned with. First determine the expression for the number of inputs, and then determine Big O in terms of that quantity. Which can be tricky: in this specific example, the size of `m` may very well be entirely irrelevant, given larger and larger `n`.

Comment: Also I'm not quite sure I follow your example: your initial description sounds like you're trying to find the maximum product in `m`-sized slices. E.g. slice 1 has product 2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*2 (because 1 is multiplicative identity), slice 2 has product 0 (because there are zeroes the _entire slice_ is zero). slice 3 is either zero, or some other number, and so forth until we reach the end of the number, and we return the highest valued product we found. But that is not what your code example suggests you're doing. Instead, you're "skipping over" zeroes. What is the exact problem statement?

Comment: Hi Mike, I apologize, I was not clear. I updated the question with the problem statement. please have a look.  For the matrix problem yes, that's my mistake. I was thinking of it as n - columns and m - rows.

Comment: An observation: you don't need to multiply anything while searching. All you care about is running through the 1000 digit string with a 13 digit window in a way that if you slide right, the digit you gain on the right is of higher value than the digit you lost on the left. If that is not the case, you store your "best set so far", and then you move the entire window over and repeat. You only actually need to multiply things when you need to decide whether to replace the "best so far" with the previous "best so far". So in that scenario, how many steps are required, based on `n` digits?

Comment: Ohh yes, that's another big improvement. Then, in that case, it should be `n steps` in total, taking into consideration that the product(of 13 digits ) will be calculated very less number of times. That makes it O(n) worst-case right?

Comment: We're basically looking at `O(m*n)` worst case, and because `m` is a constant, it does not factor into the complexity, and we get `O(n)`.